# Pass current item reference to function

Tags: knockout.js

In knockoutjs how do I pass the current item reference to a function?

I have a photo gallery that I'm looping over, when the user clicks the photo I want to check if photo the user is selecting has a specific class in the img tag.

Here is my current code which is not working.

```
my.Character = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.text = ko.observable();
    self.value = ko.observable();
    self.image = ko.observable();
    self.imageSrc= ko.computed(function () {
        return "/Images/" + self.image();
    }, this);
    self.selected = function ($data) {

        if ($data.hasClass('selected')) {
          // do stuff here
        };
};
```

The view

```
<div id="thumbnailsgall" data-bind='foreach: Characters'>
    <a data-bind="click: function () { getImage(); }, attr: { rel: image, id: value }" class="thumb_nail" href="#">         
       <img class="inactive" data-bind="click: function () { selected($data); }, attr: { src: imageSrc }" />  
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the view ?

Comment: Sorry Damien, been trying to edit my post, but it's not diplaying my update. Here's the view:

Comment: <div id="thumbnailsgall" data-bind='foreach: Characters'>

   <a data-bind="click: function () { getImage(); }, attr: { rel: image, id: value }" class="thumb_nail" href="#">
           
        <img class="inactive" data-bind="click: function () { selected($data); }, attr: { src: imageSrc }" />
  
 </a>
                          
</div>

Comment: You just forgot to surround the html with the "Sample code {}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple to do  with the [css binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html):

I suppose you have a Characters array in the parent context which should look like this :

```
my.Parent = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.Characters = ko.observableArray();
    // stores the selected character
    self.selected = ko.observable();    
    self.select = function (character) {
        if(self.selected() === character)
            self.selected(null);
        else
            self.selected(character);
     };
};

my.Character = function () {

    self.text = ko.observable();
    self.value = ko.observable();
    self.image = ko.observable();
    self.imageSrc= ko.computed(function () {
        return "/Images/" + self.image();
    }, this);
};
```

The view

```
<div id="thumbnailsgall" data-bind='foreach: Characters'>
    <a data-bind="click: function () { getImage(); }, attr: { rel: image, id: value }" class="thumb_nail" href="#">         
       <img class="inactive" data-bind="click: $parent.select, attr: { src: imageSrc }, css :{'selected' : $parent.selected() === $data}" />  
    </a>
</div>
```

Notice that KO will implicitly pass the bound viewmodel and the event when it calls the select function (click: $parent.select).
In others KO calls

```
$parent.select($data, clickEvent)
```

That's why I can write :

```
self.select = function (character) {};
```

Comment: Hi Damien, still not working quite right -- your code will apply/toggle the .selected class to the photo the user is clicking on, allowing a user to multi-select photos -- but I want just one photo to be selected at a time -- when the user clicks a photo the .selected class is applied, but also removed from all other photos in the gallery. Regards Melt

Comment: @Melt Down, if you want to have only one photo selected at the same time you need to store the selected character in the parent context.